# Different run time after Segfault in Infinite Recursive main()

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

Just as we know,
In Linux world, infinite recusive "main()" in userspace will receive "segmentation fault" messsage, which is actually caused by stack overflow. (just as the following code)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void) 
{
    main ();
}
```

Experiment and Question:

Change code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int cnt = 0; 
void main(void) {
    printf("cnt %d\n", cnt++);
    main();
}
```

**Test environment:**

x86-64 ubuntu,
gcc-4.6

**I need your help and thanks in advance!**

**Why Segmentation fault happens in different "cnt" value:**

cnt: 523614

cnt: 523602

cnt: 523712

cnt: 523671

Comment: Why would it happen always for the same value?? You can't expect that calls to printf all cause the same amount of memory utilization.

Comment: Appreciate for your quick response. But, I am not that clear. Do You mean that: "printf" function maybe cost different memory each time and thus, stack over flow will happen in different time ?

Comment: Availability of free stack is variable.refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686774.aspx)

Comment: Btw: It's `int main(void)`!

Comment: or just `int main()` ?

Comment: Sorry for some typo in the code.

Comment: @stijn No, it is `int main (void)`. To declare a function with empty parenthesis in C is an obsolescent feature (C11 6.11.6).

Comment: @Lundin thanks for clearing that out

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to [Address space layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). If you run the slightly modified example of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int cnt = 0;
void main(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("cnt %d %p\n", cnt++, (void*)&a); fflush(stdout);
    main();
}
```

you will see that the address of `a` is not consistent over various runs of the program. Probably the initial size of the stack is also slightly randomized resulting in a slightly different number of stack frames fitting in this space.

P.S: I've added a `fflush` so the output of the program can be safely piped through for example `tail` and `grep`, otherwise buffering may blur the actual last line of output.

P.S2: I had to change `print` into `printf` and add `#include <stdio.h>`.

P.S3: You should not use an optimization on your program, because otherwise a tail-call optimization will remove your recursion and your program will actually loop forever. My version of the program doesn't do that, because of the aliased `a`.

Comment: Doesn't GCC need an explicit order through some compiler option to perform recursion unrolling?

Comment: @Lundin I don't think _recursion unrolling_ is the same as _tail-call optimization_. In this case the call to `main` can be replaced by a jump to `main`, or more correctly to just after the prologue of `main`. My `gcc` does this at `-O2`.